# Print out the alias'd command when using the alias

Tags: bash, alias

I am trying to get alias's setup so that they print out the command, then run the command.

Ex:

```
> alias ls='ls -alh'
> ls
  Running "ls -alh"
  total 1.8G
  drwxr-x--- 36 root   root   4.0K Apr 23 09:44 ./
  drwxr-xr-x 28 root   root   4.0K Mar  6 17:24 ../
```

Is this possible? I was thinking of using a wrapper function, but I am unsure as to how one would acomplish this.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess that you are looking for `set -x` instead.

Comment: That LS was an example. :) I need the command to be printed for logging and liability reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an echo command in your alias before the actual command:

```
alias ls='echo "Running ls -alh"; ls -alh'
```

Comment: Oh my god, i feel so dumb. (>ლ) (However, the && is better, however I dont see where an echo would ever fail)

Answer (score 0):

```
alias ls='echo "Running ls -alh" && ls -alh'
```

This runs two commands one after the other. The first command is `echo "Running ls -alh"`, the `&&` checks the return value of the echo command, if that's `0`, then the command `ls -alh` is run. However, if for some reason there is a problem with the `echo` command and its return value is not `0` then the `ls` command won't be run.

The `&&` command can come in very handy when writing scripts to run one command only when another is successful.

Comment: When posting code in an answer, please also try to include an explanation and/or links as to *why* your answer should work so the OP and others can learn better about the problem.

Comment: sure thing, I'll elaborate